# Definition of a JavaScript promise and what is the difference to an event?

Tags: javascript

I've dealt with JavaScript years ago. So I'm familiar with the term "event" as an function which is automatically executed when a certain event happens. Please correct me in case my definition is wrong.

Now I have to deal with the language again. Try to get an idea from this promise-thing which is new to me. But can't find any good definition for it.

Can anyone give an easy to understand definition of what JavaScript promises are?

More over: They seem to me very similar to events. You define a callback-function which is automatically called when a certain event happens.

What's the difference between JavaScript-events and -promises?

Comment: Did you search anything ? Google gave me about [__69,000 results__](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20promise%20vs%20callback)

Comment: MDN seems to define it pretty well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Promises are used for **deferred** and **asyncronous** computations / operations and represents operations that **hasn't completed yet** and can actually assume different states (pending, fulfilled and rejected) (or, really, pending -> waiting, fullfilled -> success, rejected -> errror). Events are instead **interfaces** that represents an event fired by the dom, so they technically are **properties** offered by the DOM, I can't really foresee many conceptual relations between promises and events to be entirely honest.

Comment: @Rayon So then: What's the difference to an event?

Comment: @ts248, How could you relate among `Promise` and `Events` ? I'm not sure what you are asking.. :(

Comment: @Rayon Perhaps I've get it wrong. That might be possible. You define a callback-function for both. Therefore I'm considered them similar.

Comment: @ts248: Well, yes, both are things which can invoke code to execute. But, well, everything in programming is about invoking code to execute. So that's not really a meaningful similarity. Promises are a way to manage asynchronous operations which guarantee that some result (success or failure) will occur at some point in the future. Events are a way to manage signals raised by elements in the application by uncontrolled interactions, such as a user interface. For example, a promise guarantees that an AJAX call will finish in some state. But an event doesn't guarantee a user will click a button.

Comment: @ts248: As a matter of terminology, events don't use "callbacks".  They use "handlers".  Both of these things take the form of functions, because at some point pretty much everything takes the form of functions (or blocks of executable code of some kind).  But that doesn't make them the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first view, they are very similar. In events, you have a callback function, and in Promise you have a callback-function. Even more, technically, you can do almost similar stuff which Promises do only with Events.

Events and Promises both useful for Async code. I will write some abstract code to try explain. For example, you have some async code, and after that, it should alert something.

```
function someAsyncFunction() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // some long async logic here
        console.log('What the hell is Promises?');
    }, 2000);
}
someAsyncFunction();
```

Timeout here is Async, because it will run your code not in main tread and run it after some time, you not sure when exactly it happens (ofcouse here it's around 2s. less-or-more).

So now imagine, that you need to do something with result of async action. For example you have function `AsyncResultCalculator` and you need to run that function. What you will do? You have few choices:

- Pass a callback function to async code and run your function `AsyncResultCalculator` when async code complete it's work
- Define some Event (for example 'DoSomethingAfterAsync' event) and trigger that event after async code is finished or failed.
- Use promises

All this variants as result, will do only one thing - run your function `AsyncResultCalculator`. So, why we have 3 different ways to do the same result? Because it's cool! It's just different techniques to do the same stuff, but they change difficulty of your code. Some ways make your code more complicated, some ways make your code larger, some ways make your code more elegant.

So, i think you know how to run callback functions or how to trigger event, but what about Promises? How to use them? Very easy. Let's go back to Async Timeout and look:

```
function AsyncResultCalculator(res) {
    // calculate result of async action!!!
    console.log(res + 1);
}

function someAsyncFunction() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // some long async logic here
            resolve(55); // or reject
        }, 2000);
    }
}

someAsyncFunction().then(AsyncResultCalculator);
```

So, what the point to use Promises here? Just because it's modern style for async actions. With promises your code will be more elegant and more easy to read for different developers. Also, promises is useful because you can build a CHAIN of function like

```
someAsyncFunction()
    .then(function(){ ... })
    .then(function(){ ... });
```

But, of course, in some cases, it's not bad to use callbacks or events. For example, events is more useful, if you need to catch async result in some different JS file and you don't want to uses promises or callbacks in original file with async action.

All JavaScript language is mix of events, callbacks and promises ;D Use it with wise.

- Use events for DOM events or some complicated situations.
- Use promises for async actions
- Use callbacks for sync actions or where you don't want to use Promises

Answer (score 1):

> At their most basic, promises are a bit like event listeners except:

- A promise can only succeed or fail once. It cannot succeed or fail twice, neither can it switch from success to failure or vice versa.
- If a promise has succeeded or failed and you later add a success/failure callback, the correct callback will be called, even though the event took place earlier.

Check out this [JavaScript Promises: an Introduction](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)